# What are the rules for "safe" lifting of local variables referenced in a lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda

The sample below raises an IndexOutOfRangeException at the throw statement because the variable `i` is beyond its limit (e.g, is 2 when the loop covers 0 and 1).  I was expecting this code to create lambda blocks 0 and 1 which would each store a result in the corresponding array element.  I notice, from setting breakpoints, that the async tasks don't actually start to execute till I call `Task.WaitAll()`.  From the [C# Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/vstudio/bb397687%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), I understand that the compiler went out of its way to keep `i` in scope after the loop exited.

So, my questions are these:

1. Can someone suggest a way to achieve the effect I am trying to create, that each async task should store its results in a distinct slot in the array? `Task.Run()` doesn't have an overload to provide arguments (which I'd use to pass `i` in the loop), and the lambda block declaration resists my attempt to declare parameters anyway.
2. Can someone provide a justification why it is desirable behavior for a lambda expression to be able to continue to refer to a local variable after it goes out of scope in its declaring block? The C# language reference bends the very meaning of "local" declaration to cover lifting by anonymous functions and lambda blocks, but this only opens the door to picking up unexpected values, as my example shows.

Here's the sample:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncLifting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int numTasks = 2;
            double[] taskResult = new double[numTasks];
            Task<int>[] taskHandles = new Task<int>[numTasks];

            for (int i = 0; i < numTasks; i++)
            {
                taskHandles[i] = Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    DateTime startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    await Task.Delay(10);
                    try
                    {
                        taskResult[i] = (DateTime.UtcNow - startTime).TotalMilliseconds;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) { 
                        throw e;  // IndexOutOfRange, i is 2
                    }
                    return i;
                });
            }

            Task.WaitAll(taskHandles);

            Console.WriteLine("Task waits:");
            foreach (double tr in taskResult)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  {0}ms.", tr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delegate is *closing over* the variable—it's not just capturing the value at that time, but *the whole variable*. This can occasionally be useful.

Anyway, to prevent the unintended behavior, just make a new variable and use that inside the block:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int index = i;
    DoSomething(delegate() {
        myArray[index] = /* something */;
    });
}
```

Comment: But now I'm even more confused!  Am I to think that each iteration allocates a distinct "instance" of index (not in C# sense of instance of class), and that is why the first one still had value 1 when the task eventually ran?

Comment: @BobHy: Yes. Each time you enter a scope, the set of variables declared in that scope are created, distinct from variables at any previous time you entered that scope. (Not confusing variables and their values.)

Answer (score 1):

icktoofay has provided an excellent answer to your first question.

As for why this is useful behaviour, well, if local variables were deleted as soon as they went out of scope, you wouldn't be able to reference anything outside of the lambda's local variables, because the lambda might last a lot longer than it's context would if the lambda weren't deliberately keeping it around.

More concretely consider this function from perhaps a game library (I recently did something like this)

```
public static Func<double,Point> MakeSimpleVelocityTrajectory(double xv, double yv, double x0, double y0)
{
    return (t) => {
        return new Point(x0+xv*t,y0+yv*t);
    }
}
```

If the lambda didn't keep the local variables around there would be no point to returning the lambda since it wouldn't be able to do anything because the variables it references are no longer around.

Comment: You could still do that if you're just copying the values of the variables at that point. I think a more useful example of why you want references would be, say, putting a bunch of delegates in a `Dictionary<string, Action>` and making a sort of menu or command system with that.

Comment: oh certainly, I hadn't realized that was what the op was expecting, that certainly makes more sense, but suppose you have something similar except not static, but it uses some properties of your surrounding class. You usually want it to refer to those properties, not their values at the creation of the lambda. Otherwise you'd have to recreate the lambda every time some field or property changed.

Comment: If (to be perverse) you only decided to copy local variables then, well... I suppose that might work, but it can be useful, if for example you want to reuse a lambda that has configuration parameters local to the method which you then change later in the method. (Who knows why, just an example of why it might be useful)

Comment: Well, if `this` is a reference type, then copying it as a value actually just copies the reference, so properties will stay ‘live’. Yes, I absolutely agree that having it keep references is useful, but the OP would not have had a problem if values were copied, so it would be better to have an example that showed not only why you should be able to reference variables in the parent scope, but also that they're *actually the same variable* rather than another variable with a copied value.

Comment: I decided to write out the menu example I was thinking of. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=hXJHhuz9 Unlike your current example, it demonstrates a case that *needs* references to variables to be kept, rather than just their values.

Comment: @icktoofay Thinking more about the example, I'd say that it does show how delegates/lambda can take advantage of closure of outer-scope variables, but it also shows the limitations.  Is it right to say the delegate that sets 'done' would not terminate any command loop other than the one it was created in, even if that loop control variable were named 'done'? Because that would be a different instance than the one closed in the delegate?  If so, I have to choose: reference any variables but only in original scope or execute in any scope, but reference only some, carefully reviewed variables.